# Remove a package via script in xamarin forms

Tags: shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild, build-script

I have a build build script(MyBuild.sh) set up for creating the Android apk for a xamarin forms application.

My requirement is when i give the internal test builds i want the microsoft app center crashes and analytics in the the project csproj but when i take the PROD builds i don't want the microsoft app center crashes and analytics in the project

so in the build script i check whether its a PROD build and tried to remove the app center packages from the csproj.

```
if [ $Env == 'PROD' ]
then
    dotnet remove ./Sample/Sample.csproj package Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics
    dotnet remove ./Droid/Sample.Droid.csproj package Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes
fi
```

My problem is when the script is executed it correctly removes the package from the Shared Code but not from the Droid.csproj and while trying to remove the package it throws

```
info : Removing PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes' from project './Droid/Sample.Droid.csproj'.
error: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  /Users/george.thomas/Documents/Nov/Candidate/Droid/Sample.Droid.csproj
```

Now if i remove the MSBuildExtensionsPath from the Droid.csproj and run the script it correctly removes the packages but the project cant be built
throwning `The target "Build" does not exist in the project`

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: Why are you using `dotnet` to remove the package(?), use msbuild (or nuget) directly against the project (and assigning the solution dir option) to remove the package and the "imported project" error will go away (`dotnet` does not know anything about Xamarin.Android targets)

Comment: @SushiHangover Is there any documentation or example that i can refer to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference